Issue Adding "django.contrib.gis" to INSTALLED_APPS in Django
I'm currently developing an application using Django and aiming to integrate geospatial functionalities by adding "django.contrib.gis" to my project's INSTALLED_APPS. However, upon adding this module to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file, I encounter the following error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal307", "gdal306", "gdal305", "gdal304", "gdal303", "gdal302", "gdal301", "gdal300", "gdal204"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings

Despite having the GDAL library installed in the directory C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\gdal-data, specifying the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in the settings.py file doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Additionally, I have installed PostGIS via the Application Stack Builder in PostgreSQL.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully integrate "django.contrib.gis" into my Django project. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I recommend setting up your project in a Docker container. This approach can help you avoid many of the issues you're facing on Windows

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
